# Styles quit working in iOS 10

Tags: cordova, polymer, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, ios10

recently I observed my app is not working in iOS 10. All the style are gone. Previously it was working fine. I am using cordova and polymer for material design. Is there any update on polymer for iOS 10 ? Please help me to resolve this one ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've used Polymer and cordova(no Phonegap) on ios9.3 device and ios10 emulator and the styling works for me.

Comment: is there any updation I need to do or ? If I want to try with the new app from where I can try ? I was following the below link [install link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/)

Comment: should work....is it rendering properly in browser?

Comment: no, in the web view also it's not coming properly.

Comment: Then there should be some problem with your code. Can you post your code?

Comment: I have followed the same steps are mentioned in the [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/) But when I add the code to index.html below error is coming.polymer-micro.html:74 Uncaught TypeError: prototype.registerCallback is not a function

Comment: I have added <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.3/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/v1.0.3/polymer-micro.html"> That error has gone and its working in the browser. But not working in the ios 10 mobile.

Comment: some suggestions instead of using `rawgit` use local elements and you don't need `webcomponents` full version use `webcomponents-lite.min.js` and full version of `polymer` `polymer.html`.

Comment: Check in your ios app if these imports are present or not and if they are getting imported or not

Comment: Again, it'll be lot easier if you can post your code

Comment: I tried pasting the code. But the length is large.can you share your email id that would be helpful for me to resolve.

Comment: paste relavant parts

Comment: [Its here](https://jsbin.com/caxere/edit?html,output)

Comment: Are these imports present in your bower_component folder?

Comment: One more thing which i didn't notice earlier is that the link that you posted is using Polymer0.5 current version of Polymer is 1.6.x and there were breaking changes from 0.x to 1.x. So i'd recommend you to use 1.x version. Just create a  normal polymer project inside cordova and try

Comment: Is there any other link where I can create a polymer project apart from which Iam following ? And also how to update the polymer for a current project?

Comment: you can follow polymer's official website. Until you have large project i'll recommend you to start from scratch rather than migrating

Comment: [Link here](https://jsbin.com/zoqisem/edit?html,output) the above code is working in the but not in the mobile what is the mistake am doing ? :(

Comment: Missing import of `polymer.html`

Comment: even after adding polymer.html no use. [Link](https://jsbin.com/zoqisem/1/edit?html,output) in iOS 10 white screen is coming.

Comment: I don't see any mistake in your code. You should try using Safari's dev tool to debug your ios app.

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Polymer I am getting this error.

Comment: Some where I found in polymer 1.0 the syntax are changed so, Is that do I need to take care ?

Comment: If you say that your 1.x code is working fine in browser then it should be syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Same problems happened to me but after applying new 'Content-Security-Policy', problem solved. 
Here's my Content-Security-Policy for your record.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'">
```